# Resource files falsely enumerated as part of project

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, resx, envdte

We have a localized WinForms application.

When we get translations from 3rd party, new *..resx files appear in the project folders and need to be added to the projects.

For common resource files, e.g. Properties\Resources.de.resx, nothing changes when new files are present, but for the WinForms controls the new files, e.g. AboutBox.de.resx, appear in the solution explorer with a gray dotted icon, even if "Show All Files" is not checked.

To add these new files to the project we use a Visual Studio Extension; it's using EnvDTE model to enumerate all EnvDTE.ProjectItem of all projects, and checks if additional resource files are in the folder but not yet in the project.

Now for the WinForms resources the new files are already enumerated as part of the project (like they are shown in solution explorer) and we can't find a way to distinguish if the item is a real project member or a fake one.

Is there a way to switch of the "feature" of enumerating fake project items for WinForms resources, or any other means to detect these fake items and add them as real items?

Comment: You can read the content of the resx. file to determine if you  got the right file or not

Comment: It is the right file an I can read it - the problem is that it looks as if it's already a part of the project.
See e.g. AboutForm.zh-CN.resx: [Solution Explorer](http://1drv.ms/1ISVRTZ) - the file is in the folder and it's enumerated as a ProjectItem, but when you build, there is no Chinese translation.